# What is a good design for an interface with optional components?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I have an interface that supports a few potential operations:

```
interface Frobnicator {
    int doFoo(double v);
    int doBar();
}
```

Now, some instances will only support one or the other of these operations.  They may support both.  The client code won't necessarily know until it actually gets one from the relevant factory, via dependency injection, or wherever it is getting instances from.

I see a few ways of handling this.  One, which seems to be the general tactic taken in the Java API, is to just have the interface as shown above and have unsupported methods raise `UnsupportedOperationException`.  This has the disadvantage, however, of not being fail-fast - client code can't tell whether `doFoo` will work until it tries to call `doFoo`.

This could be augmented with `supportsFoo()` and `supportsBar()` methods, defined to return true iff the corresponding `do` method works.

Another strategy is to factor the `doFoo` and `doBar` methods into `FooFrobnicator` and `BarFrobnicator` methods, respectively.  These methods would then return `null` if the operation is unsupported.  To keep the client code from having to do `instanceof` checks, I define a `Frobnicator` interface as follows:

```
interface Frobnicator {
    /* Get a foo frobnicator, returning null if not possible */
    FooFrobnicator getFooFrobnicator();
    /* Get a bar frobnicator, returning null if not possible */
    BarFrobnicator getBarFrobnicator();
}

interface FooFrobnicator {
    int doFoo(double v);
}

interface BarFrobnicator {
    int doBar();
}
```

Alternatively, `FooFrobnicator` and `BarFrobnicator` could extend `Frobnicator`, and the `get*` methods possibly be renamed `as*`.

One issue with this is naming: the `Frobnicator` really isn't a frobnicator, it's a way of getting frobnicators (unless I use the `as*` naming).  It also gets a tad unwieldy.  The naming may be further complicated, as the `Frobnicator` will be retrieved from a `FrobnicatorEngine` service.

Does anyone have any insight into a good, preferably well-accepted solution to this problem?  Is there an appropriate design pattern?  Visitor is not appropriate in this case, as the client code needs a particular type of interface (and should preferably fail-fast if it can't get it), as opposed to dispatching on what kind of object it got.  Whether or not different features are supported can vary on a variety of things - the implementation of `Frobnicator`, the run-time configuration of that implementation (e.g. it supports `doFoo` only if some system service is present to enable `Foo`), etc.

**Update:** Run-time configuration is the other monkey wrench in this business.  It may be possible to carry the FooFrobnicator and BarFrobnicator types through to avoid the problem, particularly if I make heaver use of Guice-modules-as-configuration, but it introduces complexity into other surrounding interfaces (such as the factory/builder that produces Frobnicators in the first place).  Basically, the implementation of the factory that produces frobnicators is configured at run-time (either via properties or a Guice module), and I want it to make it fairly easy for the user to say "hook up this frobnicator provider an this client".  I admit that it's a problem with potential inherent design problems, and that I may also be overthinking some of the generalization issues, but I'm going for some combination of least-ugliness and least-astonishment.

Comment: There is in fact a third option : having `Frobnicator extends FooFrobnicator, BarFrobnicator`. A component that is only a `FooFrobnicator` will only support `doFoo()`, while a `BarFrobnicator` will only support `doBar()`. What's the problem with this one ?

Comment: @Riduidel then a class providing `Frobnicator` but only supporting `doFoo()` must also implement `BarFrobnicator`, reducing the problem to the first interface I presented.  I've thought some about how to carry the types through to allow the specific interfaces to be used directly, but it makes run-time configuration a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a problem if you are saying that  class FooImpl implements interface Foo, but it doesn't really implement ALL of Foo.  The interface is supposed to be a contract indicating what methods the implementing class (at minimum) implement.

If something is calling the FooFactory to get a Foo object, the object should be able to do what Foos do.

So, where do you go from there?  I'd suggest your composition idea is a good one, using inheritance slightly less so.

Composition would work exactly as you have it with the `getFooFrobnicator()` and `getBarFrobnicator()` methods.  If you don't like that your `Frobnicator` doesn't really frobnicate, call it a `FrobnicatorHolder`.

Inheritance would have your `Frobnicator` containing only the methods that all Frobnicators have, and the sub-interfaces would have the additional methods.

```
public interface Frobnicator{
   public void frobnicate();
}

public interface FooFrobnicator{
   public void doFoo();
}

public interface BarFrobnicator{
   public void doBar();
}
```

You could then use `if (frobnicator instanceof FooFrobnicator) { ((FooFrobnicator) frobnicator).doFoo() }` and life goes on.

Favor composition over inheritance.  You'll be happier.

Comment: So far, composition is winning unless I do find a good way to push the real interfaces all the way through the system.

Comment: I ultimately went with the composition approach, having a `FrobnicatorEngine` with `getFooFrobnicator` and `getBarFrobnicator` methods (each returning null if not supported by that particular engine).  You are right, attempting to shoe-horn inheritance where composition is more appropriate is unnecessary and inappropriate pain.  The composition-based API is much cleaner.  I may still try to find a way to push the real types through, so things get FooFrobnicators, etc. rater than engines, but that's future work.

Answer (score 4):

> I see a few ways of handling this. One, which seems to be the general tactic taken in the Java API, is to just have the interface as shown above and have unsupported methods raise UnsupportedOperationException. This has the disadvantage, however, of not being fail-fast - client code can't tell whether doFoo will work until it tries to call doFoo.

As you said, the general tactic is to use the [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern. An excellent example is the [`HttpServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

Here's how you could achieve the same.

```
public interface Frobnicator {
    int doFoo(double v);
    int doBar();
}
```

---

```
public abstract class BaseFrobnicator implements Frobnicator {
    public int doFoo(double v) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public int doBar() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * This concrete frobnicator only supports the {@link #doBar()} method.
 */
public class ConcreteFrobnicator extends BaseFrobnicator {
    public int doBar() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

The client has just to read the docs and handle the `UnsupportedOperationException` accordingly. Since it's a `RuntimeException`, it's a perfect case for a "programmer error". True, it's not fail-fast (i.e. not compiletime), but that's what you get paid for as developer. Just prevent it or catch and handle it.

Comment: Fail-fast is not the same thing as checked at compile time.  Fail-fast lets the client code ask ahead of time "will this work?" so it doesn't bother trying (which may involve expensive set-up) if it won't work.  Also, `UnsupportedOperationException` is a violation of the spirit of Liskov substitutability (in some ways, my whole setup in the question also is, but I'm looking for the least-hideous way to solve it).

Comment: As to fail-fast, I didn't mean to imply that it means exactly that. I was just referring to the template method pattern in general. As to Liskov, that concerns in this case the functional requirement, not the possible approaches. By the way, the `HttpServlet` offers a `doOptions()` method which checks the supported methods by reflection. You may want to consider the same. A completely different alternative is to redesign the whole thing to have only one method which takes another interface as argument so that the client can supply the algorithm himself, have a look at strategy pattern.

Answer (score 2):

How about just adding empty non-implementation methods rather than throwing `UnsupportedOperationExceptions`? This way, calling an unsupported method will have no side-effects, and won't cause a run-time error.

If you do want to be able to tell if a certain object supports a method or not, I would suggest you split your interface up into two with a common super interface, and then type check whatever object you get handed to determine what methods are supported. This is probably cleaner, and more advisable than my first suggestion.

```
interface Frobnicator {}

interface FooFrobnicator extends Frobnicator {
    void doFoo();
}

interface BarFrobnicator extends Frobnicator {
    void doBar();
}
```

**Edit:**

Another way of doing it would be to add a boolean return type to your methods, and make sure that they only return false if the method is not supported. Hence:

```
interface Frobnicator 
{
    boolean doFoo();
    boolean doBar();
}

class FooFrobnicator implements Frobnicator 
{
    public boolean doFoo() { code, code, code; return true; }
    public boolean doBar() { return false; }
}
```

Comment: The methods are slightly more complex; no-ops won't work.  I've updated the question to reflect this.  Also, if the object doesn't support `doFoo`, then the client may be able to avoid doing work to prepare for a `doFoo` that won't work.  I've thought about the interface solution as well; the enhanced second method I describe in the question is essentially a refinement of this (to avoid the need for client code to do `instanceof` checks and casts).

Comment: Basically identical to my answer, so I've deleted it. +1

Comment: @Michael E - you avoid the need for the client to do `instanceof`, but they still have to check the returned interfaces for `null`. Why invent a more verbose, custom way of doing something that the language already supports?

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker because returning `null` (particularly with composition rather than inheritance) allows the availability of features to depend on run-time constraints (such as some feature of the database system).

Comment: True, though you could achieve that by returning a different derived class depending on the config. Depends how many optional methods you're going to have and how many combinations thereof.

Comment: @Micheal E, I've added another suggestion in an edit. Maybe that could work for you?

Comment: @Banang The return values of my methods are meaningful; I could potentially define an out-of-domain error return such as `null` or `-1`, but in that case I might as well throw `UnsupportedOperationException` - the issue isn't the specific exception, but the fact that client code can't tell ahead-of-time whether it will work (and that it is an egregious abuse of Liskov substitutability).  The exception at least has the benefit of automatically propagating up the call stack.

Comment: @Michael E, I didn't realise you'd changed the return type in your question, sorry. If proper substitutability is what you want, then you need to have every class committing to your interface implement all the methods in that interface...

Comment: @Banang that's fine - I thought I had indicated in a comment that I had edited the question, but evidently I neglected to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious solution  is to just define two interfaces FooFrobnicator and BarFrobnicator. This should be fine as class can implement multiple interfaces.

You could then provide a super (marker) interface if necessary.

Comment: +1 If you're saying that, to satisfy the Frobnicator interface, an object should do foo or bar, or maybe both - that's a bad interface.  That's bad design.  You've got Fooers and Barrers, and some of your objects are both - let the class design reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is to add `supports*()` methods,

If you think that is not good style, then just forget about `Frobnicator` (it gives you very little as it is not an interface you can rely on) and code directly against `FooFrobnicator` and `BarFrobnicator`, and if they happen to be implemented by the same object, fine. This also gives you the possibility of requiring a specific interface in client code:

```
interface FooFrobnicator {
    doFoo();
}

interface BarFrobnicator {
    doBar();
}

public class Client {
     ...
     FooFrobnicator fooFrobnicator;
     public void setFooFrobnicator(FooFrobnicator fooFrobnicator) {
         this.fooFrobnicator = fooFrobnicator;
     }

     BarFrobnicator barFrobnicator;
     public void setBarFrobnicator(BarFrobnicator barFrobnicator) {
         this.barFrobnicator = barFrobnicator;
     }
     ...
     public void doSomething() {
         ...
         if (fooFrobnicator != null) { ... }
         ...
         if (barFrobnicator != null) { ... }
     }
}
...
public class FrobnicatorImpl implements FooFrobnicator, BarFrobnicator { ... }
...
public void doSomething() {
    ...
    FrobnicatorImpl impl = new FrobnicatorImpl();
    Client client = new Client();        
    client.setFooFrobnicator(impl);
    client.setBarFrobnicator(impl);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, you're making this way too complicated. Do away with the interface. Create a base class with the commonly used methods (they can even do nothing in the base class if you don't know how to implement them there). Then extend the base class & implement/override whichever methods you need.